# Can I install the AMD graphics card driver in Linux?

Tags: gpu-driver, amdgpu

I want to install the graphic card driver on UBUNTU ATI RADEON HD 8490.
In this site it says that the graphic card doesn't work on newer versions of Linux:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD
Is this true?

Comment: Anyone? Can I please get an answer?

Comment: The first paragraph of this source state :  ' This entire article is obsolete.'  Moreover, it applies on Ubuntu 16.04.  I would search other references for what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: This question was also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2484012  Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choices; thus more than a single kernel is available, meaning different kernel modules (aka *drivers*) are available for the same release. It's best if you check the system yourself on your actual hardware, as GPU is only one part of your total machine.

Comment: Ubuntu automatically installs AMD drivers, isn't it? Why do you think you need to do anything?

Answer (score 0):

> In this site it says that the graphic card doesn't work on newer
> versions of Linux

No.

The reference you provided is talking about a specific *driver* or kernel module.

**The graphics card can still be used**, with different kernel modules, you just cannot use that *driver* or **kernel module** (*fglrx*) in more recent versions of the Linux kernel.

Please note:  Linux is both an kernel, plus a common reference to what I like calling GNU/Linux, ie. an OS.  My android phone runs Linux too, but I'd not call that an Linux machine. Ubuntu and Linux are not limited to using a single *driver* or kernel module for hardware.

Comment: Actually it's a pretty good answer despite the lack of (Linux kernel) support.

Comment: The question as worded (*my understanding*) mixes two concepts; firstly there is an implication ("*install the graphic card driver*") that a specific kernel module is needed; then it asks "*the **graphic card** doesn't work on newer versions of Linux*" where AMD have stated it's not required; as the open-source driver/kernel module is now *good enough*.  I've read *opinions* where open source works great, and others where it's not good enough ; but that's opinion & testing it on actual hardware, with your exact usage is the only real test (*what I marked this question a duplicate of*). @karel

Comment: fyi:  this answer is of "*no value*" as I see it; I recall writing tons about *fglrx* years ago when it was "*news*".. it was mostly written due to *first comment* or OP wanting 'answer', when I believe the question itself is incorrect.. I've also see this question asked by the OP more than once.  My detail on UF was more about *trying* it on the actual hardware, even though I used no links (*they'd already been provided by prior posters*).